# Leibniz rule integral

Tags: calculus

We have:

$$F(u,v)=\int_0^v\frac{1-cos(ut)}{t} dt $$

Find $$F_u$$ and $$F_v$$

which is:

$$ F_u=\int_0^v \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \frac{-cos(ut)}{t}dt = \int_0^v sin(ut) dt = \frac{-cos(uv)}{u}-\frac{(-cos(0)}{u}=\frac{1-cos(uv)}{u}$$

$$ F_v = \frac{1-cos(uv)}{v} $$

But how do can you use this to solve:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{x^2} \frac{1-cos(xt)}{t}dt $$

Obviously $$ u=x$$ and $$v=x^2$$

By Leibniz rule we have:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{x^2} \frac{1-cos(xt)}{t}dt  = F_u + f(x^2)*v' =\frac{1-cosuv}{u}+\frac{1-cosuv}{v}*2x=3*\frac{1-cosx^3}{x}$$

Feels like I have done something wrong, but is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \int^{x^2}_{0} \frac{1 - \cos(xt)}{t} dt &= \int^{x^2}_{0} \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1 - \cos(xt)}{t} dt + \frac{1 - \cos(xt)}{t}\Bigg|_{t=x^2}\frac{d}{dt}(x^2) - \frac{1 - \cos(xt)}{t}\Bigg|_{t=0}\frac{d}{dt}(0)\\
%%%%
&=\int^{x^2}_{0} \sin(xt) dt + \frac{1 - \cos(x^3)}{x^2} 2x\\
&=-\frac{1}{x}\cos(xt)\Bigg|^{t=x^2}_{t=0} + 2\frac{1 - \cos(x^3)}{x}\\
&= \frac {\left(1 - \cos(x^3)\right)}{x} + 2\frac{1 - \cos(x^3)}{x}\\
&= 3\frac{1 - \cos(x^3)}{x}\\
\end{align}
It looks like you're right. :)